# Is there a good book or article about using a Mac from a Windows user's perspective?

Tags: windows, mac

I am pretty darn good at Windows, been using it since 3.11 for Workgroups (ah the memories...). But my mother just bought a Mac and I'm struggling to load a dos prompt (joke..).

Any good guides on using a Mac from the perspective of someone very used to Windows? I'm assuming there is, it seems like a very common challenge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first DOS Prompt = Utilities --> Terminal.  Now if you want to customize the prompt in the terminal, type man prompt...  There's all the instructions...

Second, why not check Apple's web site?  [Switch 101](http://www.apple.com/support/switch101/)

> Welcome to the Mac family! If you're a PC user who has just switched to the
>   Mac and want to find out how to adapt your old working habits to the Mac OS,
>   you've come to the right place.  Welcome to Switch 101: The former PC
>   user's guide to getting the most out of your Mac.
>
> Whether you want to learn how to get around and access everything on your
>   Mac; find out how to move your old PC files to the Mac OS environment;
>   figure out how to connect your printer, iPod, digital camera, or
>   other device; learn how to do those tasks you did on a PC on a Mac; learn
>   how to use the software that came with your Mac; or even find out what to do
>   when things don't go as planned; we have the answers.

There's also the [Mac 101 Starter course online as well..](http://www.apple.com/support/mac101/)

Comment: I concur the switch guide from Apple is quite good for long time windows user.